# Finding neighbours in Pandas based on shared nodes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nearest-neighbor

I have a dataframe with FEM elements and their nodes.
I need to find the neighboring elements from this data together with their respective location.
The example data looks like this:

```
| El_ID | Node_SW | Node_NW | Node_NE | Node_SE |
|-------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 755   | 1412    | 1413    | 1459    | 1458    |
| 756   | 1413    | 1414    | 1460    | 1459    |
| 802   | 1458    | 1459    | 1505    | 1504    |
```

Comparing **(Node_SW, Node_SE)** with **(Node_NW, Node_NE)** yields a neighbor element
**756** as *Neighbor_North* to **755** and vice versa. Comparing (Node_NE, Node_SE) with (Node_NW, Node_SW) yields western and eastern neighbors respectively.

The output should look something like this

```
| El_ID | Node_SW | Node_NW | Node_NE | Node_SE | El_S | El_N |El_W|El_E|...
|-------|---------|---------|---------|---------|------|------|----|----|...
| 755   | 1412    | 1413    | 1459    | 1458    |  754 |  756 | 802| 708|...
| 756   | 1413    | 1414    | 1460    | 1459    |  755 |  NaN | 803| 709|...
| 802   | 1458    | 1459    | 1505    | 1504    |  801 |  803 | 849| 755|...
...
```

The Element_IDs can be sorted, but it is usually random.
I have managed to get the neighborhood of an element by the distance of element width by using KDTree from scipy, but I do not get any location information (S, N, E, W).

Anybody has an idea how it could be done with pandas or numpy?
I would like to evade for loops because the element tables can be reaaaaly long....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pandas you can do the following:

```
data = [[755   , 1412    , 1413    , 1459    , 1458],    
         [756   , 1413    , 1414    , 1460    , 1459] ,  
         [802  , 1458    , 1459    , 1505    , 1504]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['El_ID',  'Node_SW' , 'Node_NW' , 'Node_NE' , 'Node_SE'])
```

then to get the neighbour following the relation Node_SW - Node_NW,

```
pd.merge(df, df, left_on= 'Node_SW', right_on='Node_NW')
```

the output is

```
    El_ID_x     Node_SW_x   Node_NW_x   Node_NE_x   Node_SE_x   El_ID_y     Node_SW_y   Node_NW_y   Node_NE_y   Node_SE_y
0   756     1413    1414    1460    1459    755     1412    1413    1459    1458
```

You get the relation between 756 and 755.

You have to do the same for the other quadrants.